# d3 Axis Label Update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have tried every permutation of this I can think of, but can not get the axis labels to clear and reset.  I am creating a heatmap that updates via a dropdown menu.  The graph shows up and the heatmap data draws correctly.  The issue I am having is that every time the chart gets updated, all of the x-axis labels for the new data get appended as the data updates (but if I go back to a previously loaded set of data, it doesn't append it uses the old labels).  I have tried to create a function that gets called when the dropdown changes that "clears" the graph and then calls another function to "redraw" it.  I've tried to make the labels variables, and so on looking at a bunch of examples.

Even if I run a .remove() - and I have done this on the svg, the g, by g.class, etc.  The axis labels just hang on, even though running the remove makes that DOM element disappear.  It seems to have to do with the .exit .remove pattern, but I can't figure out the sequence?  Any help would be great.

```
var dates = [];
var bacteria = [];

var itemHeight = 30,
  itemWidth = 12,
  cellSize = itemHeight - 1,
  margin = {
    top: 120,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 80
  };

var e = document.getElementById("level");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

var title = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
var newtitle = document.getElementById("thelevel").innerHTML=title;

d3.json("./javascripts/biome/biome_new.json").then(function(response) {
  var data = response;

  data.forEach(e => e.ubiome = e.ubiome.filter(e => e.tax_rank === value));

  dates = data.map(function(d) {
    return d.sample_date;
  })

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    bacteria.push(data[i].ubiome.slice(0, data[i].ubiome.length));
  }
  var bacteriaList = d3.merge(bacteria).map(function(d) {
    return d.tax_name
  });

  bacteriaList = d3.set(bacteriaList).values();

  var width = bacteriaList.length*itemWidth,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var y_elements = dates,
    x_elements = bacteriaList;

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(x_elements)
    .range([0, x_elements.length * itemWidth]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d;
    });

  var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(y_elements)
    .range([0, y_elements.length * itemHeight]);

  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      return  moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    });

  var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateOrRd)
    .domain([0, 10000]);

  var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var parents = svg.selectAll('svg')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(0," + yScale(d.sample_date) + ")" });

  var children = parents.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function(d) { return d.ubiome; })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'cell')
    .attr('width', 15)
    .attr('height', cellSize)
    .attr('x', function(d) {  return xScale(d.tax_name); })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
      return colorScale(d.count_norm);
    });

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
    .attr('font-weight', 'normal');

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
    .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("dx", ".8em")
    .attr("dy", "1.2em")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(-90)";
    });

    // Remove old elements
  parents.exit().remove();
  children.exit().remove();

});

function clearData(){
  bacteriaList = [];
  dates = [];

  var somemap = d3.selectAll("#heatmap");
  somemap.select("svg").remove();
  d3.select('#heatmap').html("");
  updateData();
}

function updateData(option) {
  var e = document.getElementById("level");
  var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

  var title = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
  var newtitle = document.getElementById("thelevel").innerHTML=title;

  d3.json("./javascripts/biome/biome_new.json").then(function(response) {
    var data = response;

    data.forEach(e => e.ubiome = e.ubiome.filter(e => e.tax_rank === value));

    dates = data.map(function(d) {
      return d.sample_date;
    })

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      bacteria.push(data[i].ubiome.slice(0, data[i].ubiome.length));
    }
    var bacteriaList = d3.merge(bacteria).map(function(d) {
      return d.tax_name
    });

    bacteriaList = d3.set(bacteriaList).values();

    var width = bacteriaList.length*itemWidth,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var y_elements = dates,
      x_elements = bacteriaList;

    var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(x_elements)
      .range([0, x_elements.length * itemWidth]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
      .scale(xScale)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d;
      });

    var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(y_elements)
      .range([0, y_elements.length * itemHeight]);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(yScale)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return  moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      });

    var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateOrRd)
      .domain([0, 10000]);

    var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parents = svg.selectAll('svg')
      .data(data)
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(0," + yScale(d.sample_date) + ")" });

    var children = parents.selectAll('rect')
      .data(function(d) { return d.ubiome; })
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'cell')
      .attr('width', 15)
      .attr('height', cellSize)
      .attr('x', function(d) {  return xScale(d.tax_name); })
      .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return colorScale(d.count_norm);
      });

    var they = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('font-weight', 'normal');

    var thex = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .attr("dx", ".8em")
      .attr("dy", "1.2em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(-90)";
      });

      they.exit().remove();
      thex.exit().remove();

  });
}
```

```js
var data = [{
    "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ubiome": [
      {
        "taxon": 1,
        "parent": 0,
        "count": 56085,
        "count_norm": 999999,
        "tax_name": "root",
        "tax_rank": "root"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 2,
        "parent": 131567,
        "count": 56085,
        "count_norm": 999999,
        "tax_name": "Bacteria",
        "tax_rank": "superkingdom"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 237,
        "parent": 49546,
        "count": 284,
        "count_norm": 5063,
        "tax_name": "Flavobacterium",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 543,
        "parent": 91347,
        "count": 21,
        "count_norm": 374,
        "tax_name": "Enterobacteriaceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 579,
        "parent": 543,
        "count": 21,
        "count_norm": 374,
        "tax_name": "Kluyvera",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 712,
        "parent": 135625,
        "count": 2,
        "count_norm": 35,
        "tax_name": "Pasteurellaceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 724,
        "parent": 712,
        "count": 2,
        "count_norm": 35,
        "tax_name": "Haemophilus",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 729,
        "parent": 724,
        "count": 2,
        "count_norm": 35,
        "tax_name": "Haemophilus parainfluenzae",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 815,
        "parent": 171549,
        "count": 14662,
        "count_norm": 261424,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroidaceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 816,
        "parent": 815,
        "count": 14625,
        "count_norm": 260764,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides",
        "tax_rank": "class"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sample_date": "2017-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ubiome": [
        {
          "taxon": 357276,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 5150,
          "count_norm": 76679,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides dorei",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 360807,
          "parent": 841,
          "count": 60,
          "count_norm": 893,
          "tax_name": "Roseburia inulinivorans",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 371599,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 3,
          "count_norm": 44,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides sp. XB12B",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 375288,
          "parent": 171551,
          "count": 1357,
          "count_norm": 20204,
          "tax_name": "Parabacteroides",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 376806,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 1050,
          "count_norm": 15633,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides gallinarum",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 387661,
          "parent": 375288,
          "count": 941,
          "count_norm": 14010,
          "tax_name": "Parabacteroides johnsonii",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 397864,
          "parent": 171551,
          "count": 891,
          "count_norm": 13266,
          "tax_name": "Barnesiella",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 418240,
          "parent": 572511,
          "count": 801,
          "count_norm": 11926,
          "tax_name": "Blautia wexlerae",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 420345,
          "parent": 31979,
          "count": 14,
          "count_norm": 208,
          "tax_name": "Lactonifactor",
          "tax_rank": "class"
        }
    ]
  }
];

var dates = [];
var bacteria = [];

var itemHeight = 30,
  itemWidth = 12,
  cellSize = itemHeight - 1,
  margin = {
    top: 120,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 80
  };

var e = document.getElementById("level");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

var title = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
var newtitle = document.getElementById("thelevel").innerHTML=title;

//d3.json("./javascripts/biome/biome_new.json").then(function(response) {

  data.forEach(e => e.ubiome = e.ubiome.filter(e => e.tax_rank === value));

  dates = data.map(function(d) {
    return d.sample_date;
  });

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    bacteria.push(data[i].ubiome.slice(0, data[i].ubiome.length));
  }
  var bacteriaList = d3.merge(bacteria).map(function(d) {
    return d.tax_name
  });

  bacteriaList = d3.set(bacteriaList).values();

  var width = bacteriaList.length*itemWidth,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var y_elements = dates,
    x_elements = bacteriaList;

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(x_elements)
    .range([0, x_elements.length * itemWidth]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d;
    });

  var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(y_elements)
    .range([0, y_elements.length * itemHeight]);

  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      return  moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    });

  var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateOrRd)
    .domain([0, 10000]);

  var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var parents = svg.selectAll('svg')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(0," + yScale(d.sample_date) + ")" });

  var children = parents.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function(d) { return d.ubiome; })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'cell')
    .attr('width', 15)
    .attr('height', cellSize)
    .attr('x', function(d) {  return xScale(d.tax_name); })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
      return colorScale(d.count_norm);
    });

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
    .attr('font-weight', 'normal');

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
    .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("dx", ".8em")
    .attr("dy", "1.2em")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(-90)";
    });

    // Remove old elements
  parents.exit().remove();
  children.exit().remove();

//});

function clearData(){
  bacteriaList = [];
  dates = [];
  var somemap = d3.selectAll("#heatmap");
  somemap.select("svg").remove();
  d3.select('#heatmap').html("");
  updateData();
}

function updateData() {

  var data = [{
      "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "ubiome": [
        {
          "taxon": 1,
          "parent": 0,
          "count": 56085,
          "count_norm": 999999,
          "tax_name": "root",
          "tax_rank": "root"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 2,
          "parent": 131567,
          "count": 56085,
          "count_norm": 999999,
          "tax_name": "Bacteria",
          "tax_rank": "superkingdom"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 237,
          "parent": 49546,
          "count": 284,
          "count_norm": 5063,
          "tax_name": "Flavobacterium",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 543,
          "parent": 91347,
          "count": 21,
          "count_norm": 374,
          "tax_name": "Enterobacteriaceae",
          "tax_rank": "family"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 579,
          "parent": 543,
          "count": 21,
          "count_norm": 374,
          "tax_name": "Kluyvera",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 712,
          "parent": 135625,
          "count": 2,
          "count_norm": 35,
          "tax_name": "Pasteurellaceae",
          "tax_rank": "family"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 724,
          "parent": 712,
          "count": 2,
          "count_norm": 35,
          "tax_name": "Haemophilus",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 729,
          "parent": 724,
          "count": 2,
          "count_norm": 35,
          "tax_name": "Haemophilus parainfluenzae",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 815,
          "parent": 171549,
          "count": 14662,
          "count_norm": 261424,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroidaceae",
          "tax_rank": "family"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 816,
          "parent": 815,
          "count": 14625,
          "count_norm": 260764,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides",
          "tax_rank": "class"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sample_date": "2017-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
      "ubiome": [
          {
            "taxon": 357276,
            "parent": 816,
            "count": 5150,
            "count_norm": 76679,
            "tax_name": "Bacteroides dorei",
            "tax_rank": "species"
          },
          {
            "taxon": 360807,
            "parent": 841,
            "count": 60,
            "count_norm": 893,
            "tax_name": "Roseburia inulinivorans",
            "tax_rank": "species"
          },
          {
            "taxon": 371599,
            "parent": 816,
            "count": 3,
            "count_norm": 44,
            "tax_name": "Bacteroides sp. XB12B",
            "tax_rank": "species"
          },
          {
            "taxon": 375288,
            "parent": 171551,
            "count": 1357,
            "count_norm": 20204,
            "tax_name": "Parabacteroides",
            "tax_rank": "genus"
          },
          {
            "taxon": 376806,
            "parent": 816,
            "count": 1050,
            "count_norm": 15633,
            "tax_name": "Bacteroides gallinarum",
            "tax_rank": "species"
          },
          {
            "taxon": 387661,
            "parent": 375288,
            "count": 941,
            "count_norm": 14010,
            "tax_name": "Parabacteroides johnsonii",
            "tax_rank": "species"
          },
          {
            "taxon": 397864,
            "parent": 171551,
            "count": 891,
            "count_norm": 13266,
            "tax_name": "Barnesiella",
            "tax_rank": "genus"
          },
          {
            "taxon": 418240,
            "parent": 572511,
            "count": 801,
            "count_norm": 11926,
            "tax_name": "Blautia wexlerae",
            "tax_rank": "species"
          },
          {
            "taxon": 420345,
            "parent": 31979,
            "count": 14,
            "count_norm": 208,
            "tax_name": "Lactonifactor",
            "tax_rank": "class"
          }
      ]
    }
  ];

  var e = document.getElementById("level");
  var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

  var title = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
  var newtitle = document.getElementById("thelevel").innerHTML=title;

  //d3.json("./javascripts/biome/biome_new.json").then(function(response) {
    //var data = response;

    data.forEach(e => e.ubiome = e.ubiome.filter(e => e.tax_rank === value));

    dates = data.map(function(d) {
      return d.sample_date;
    });

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      bacteria.push(data[i].ubiome.slice(0, data[i].ubiome.length));
    }
    var bacteriaList = d3.merge(bacteria).map(function(d) {
      return d.tax_name
    });

    bacteriaList = d3.set(bacteriaList).values();

    var width = bacteriaList.length*itemWidth,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var y_elements = dates,
      x_elements = bacteriaList;

    var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(x_elements)
      .range([0, x_elements.length * itemWidth]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
      .scale(xScale)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d;
      });

    var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(y_elements)
      .range([0, y_elements.length * itemHeight]);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(yScale)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return  moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      });

    var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateOrRd)
      .domain([0, 10000]);

    var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parents = svg.selectAll('svg')
      .data(data)
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(0," + yScale(d.sample_date) + ")" });

    var children = parents.selectAll('rect')
      .data(function(d) { return d.ubiome; })
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'cell')
      .attr('width', 15)
      .attr('height', cellSize)
      .attr('x', function(d) {  return xScale(d.tax_name); })
      .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return colorScale(d.count_norm);
      });

    var they = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('font-weight', 'normal');

    var thex = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .attr("dx", ".8em")
      .attr("dy", "1.2em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(-90)";
      });

      they.exit().remove();
      thex.exit().remove();

  //});
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #000;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
#heatmap {
  height: 400px;
  width: 1200px;
  border:2px solid #000;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <content>
        <h1></h1>
        <h4>Sort by:</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column"><select id="level" style="margin-bottom:20px;" onchange="clearData()"><option value="class">Class</option><option value="family">Family</option><option value="genus">Genus</option><option value="order">Order</option><option value="phylum">Phylum</option><option value="species">Species</option><option value="subclass">Subclass</option><option value="suborder">Suborder</option><option value="subphylum">Subphylum</option><option value="superphylum">Superphylum</option></select></div>
            <div
                class="column">
                <div id="thelevel"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="heatmap"></div>
    </content>
</body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to include a link to a gist/block or fiddle/plunkr?

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry for the delay.  I have updated my question to include a snippet.  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Not related to the question, but it would be better if the options in the dropdown were displayed according to the taxonomic rank, from superphylum (first) to species (last), the alphabetical order is not the best one. Back to the code: your update function is not correct, there are a **lot** of duplications here... I suggest you do a major refactor in this code.

Comment: Thank you Gerardo for the feedback.  The dropdown order makes sense to change.  As far as the duplications, that is where I am stuck.  What doesn't need to stay and what is responsible for updating the data.  A lot of the examples show you have to reset the bands, which means redrawing the whole thing?  But the axis still hangs on.  The data duplication is only for the fiddle to make it showcase the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that come across this, I finally figured it out myself.

The issue had to do with how the array was being stored, and may have nothing to do with d3.

Once I updated the original variable in the update function to:

```
bacteria.length = 0;
```

...everything fell into place.  That initial array was just hanging on.  Once I reset it, the update function was able to rebuild everything just fine.